# break the rules by repeating information or respect the rules?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table **songs** with the columns **title** and **author**.

An author may have created more than one song so some information will repeat in this table.

This problem could be quickly solved by creating another table **authors** (id,author) and create a reference to authors_id in **songs** table, this way i would save memory in the database, BUT my application will be actually a *search engine* that will perform a lot of queries on the **songs** table, so for example if it returns 10 results with different authors it will need to perform another 10 queries on the **authors** table to find out the authors names based on their referenced ids, that's not good because a search engine must return the results in no time.

Now, if i remove the **authors** table and i will just put the author's name directly in the **songs** table i won't need to peroform other queries, but the **songs** table will be bigger and require more memory so the return time will increase too.

How would you approach this situation?

PS: This is just a simple map similar to my problem, in reality my application and the DB are much more complex so i couldn't give out the whole thing here.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking? Don't rule out a normalized design just because it SOUNDS like denormalizing might work better.

Comment: Well you wouldnt necessarily have to query for author names.. you should just do a join in the first query. However given that this is only an example and not actually your structure that may not be relevant.

Comment: Post the `create` statements for your two tables if you want more explicit help on how to query them using joins.

Comment: When i said "it will need to perform another 10 queries on the authors table to find out the authors names" i actually intended to say "i will use joins" which are in fact some sort of queries, but still i don't think this would be clearly better.

Comment: Assume the key of Songs is CatalogNum. My assumption is that either the song determines the author (the FD: CatalogNum->AuthorName) or the song determines multiple authors (MVD: CatalogNum->>AuthorName). In both cases the determinant is CatalogNum, which is a candidate key. Therefore on the information given, the Songs table is apparently in 5NF already. So the "rules" (normalization rules) are not being broken by putting the author's name in the song table. That doesn't necessarily make it a good design but it does mean you don't need to worry about breaking rules!

Answer (score 2):

If the `songs` table stores an `author_id`, then it is trivial for you to use a `join` to return all the info you need with one query.

If you use primary keys and joins correctly your search results *will* be returned in no time.

[MySQL Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Well, of course i will use JOINs, but i called them queries, that's what they are in fact

Comment: Actually although joins may be part of a query, they are not themselves queries.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the authors name in the songs table is *not* a form of denormalization and creating a new authors table is not normalization. My assumption is that either the song determines the author or the song determines multiple authors. In that case a key in the song table is a determinant for the author's name and so respecting Boyce Codd Normal Form or Fifth Normal Form the song table would be a pefectly proper place to put the authors name.

On the understanding that there is no denormalization issue here, other considerations could still apply. There are too many variables to make assumptions about performance without knowing how the tables will be implemented in storage and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the tradeoffs of denormalization (which you appear to), and they are right for your application and design then by all means, use a denormalized table.

The fact is, for reads, a denormalized table will generally perform better than a normalized one, simply due to the fact that the database doesn't have extra joins to compute.

Of course, you should test performance of both solutions and see which one is better for your application.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to find compromise between performance and space. If you really wanted to 100% prevent information duplication, you would effectively have most tables with two columns only. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization .

But don't overoptimize. Always write the dumb solution first, test the performance and THEN optimize. Programmers are very poor at guessing the bottlenecks. Only optimize what needs to be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Testing of performance need to be done:

- how you can search on when you merge tables (JOIN)
- what is performace improvment if autors names are in songs table and if it worted to increase a space required for that solution (and index)

number of records will be important factor, but final call is yours!

You can also create a third table for searchnig only (limited info about songs and autor and idex to songs), tight it with songs by triggers and test is it imrove performance

Comment: the number of records is the main problem because the DB will get larger and larger with duplicate data

Comment: it your call - if databse size is your main concern - go with normalizated solution and eat performance of searching - I will make my decision based on numbers from tests...

Comment: the database size is not my main concern, but if its size increaseas so will the return time

Comment: If you use indexes and joins properly increases in data size should not impact return time!

Comment: Ok, i will make 2 tests with tables in this format and will return with the results tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

And what if the user asks for a list of songs of a given author? Then you search engines has to search all author name strings in the whole search table, which would be not good. And what if a song has more than one author?

You could think of normalization if you need lots of joins for a query but a single join is still extremely fast if you don't forgot to use indices for the keys.

Comment: In this is case it's supposed that a song has only one author, and if a user asks for a list of songs of a given author.. well it depends on the db structure, it could be as you said or it should look for the id of that author in authors table and then search for that author_id in the songs table, this option would be the best in this case.

Answer (score 0):

For a live database, you should do anything feasible to avoid not normalizing your data. I would absolutely create an `Author` table and add an `AuthorId` column to your `Song` table (standard table naming practice is to use the singular form of the word--you're naming a row, essentially--not the plural. I.E. `Song`, not `Songs`, just FYI).

You will almost certainly not see a performance hit by joining to an `Author` table versus duplicating the author information throughout the `Song` table.

**As a rule of thumb, you need serious justification to *avoid* normalization, not to do it.**

Comment: preformance hit is not a issue when pulling data - it almost innoticeble - it start when searching on it (song and author at same time)... however it allways number game

Comment: @bensiu: If your database is properly indexed, query performance on columns like that will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The testing results..

For this table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `song` (
`id` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` char(100) NOT NULL,
`author` char(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `author` (`author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
song    Browse  Structure   Search  Insert  Empty   Drop    100,019     MyISAM  latin1_swedish_ci   25.8 MiB
```

0.04s for SELECT title,author FROM song WHERE title='abf10924a290073ac1522aab6cd604d0';
0.00004s for SELECT title,author FROM song WHERE author='abf10924a290073ac1522aab6cd604d0'; (this is because the author field is indexed)

And for these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `author` (
`id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`author` char(100) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `author` (`author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `song` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` char(100) NOT NULL,
`authorid` int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `authorid` (`authorid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

author  Browse  Structure   Search  Insert  Empty   Drop    10,000  InnoDB  latin1_swedish_ci   4.0 MiB     -
song    Browse  Structure   Search  Insert  Empty   Drop    ~90,129     InnoDB  latin1_swedish_ci   15.0 MiB    -
```

0.3s for SELECT t1.title, t2.author FROM song t1 JOIN author t2 ON t1.authorid=t2.id WHERE t1.title='abf10924a290073ac1522aab6cd604d0';

I've also used foreign keys with InnoDB engine and the results were disastrous, 3s for the same query.

Concluding, in this case the denormalized table is almost ten times faster than the normalized table.
In both cases the table song contained about 100,000 rows with md5 hashes.

I'm waiting for your opinions, maybe i didn't use the JOINs properly and the tables were not indexed efficiently in the second case.

Comment: flowerpower: Is it a rule that a song can only have one author? In reality that seems unlikely but is that the scenario you intend to represent with this example: one song has one and only one author? If that is so then logically your first design with only one table is surely the better one. It is already in 5NF and there is no obvious reason to create a new table just for the author name. If you wanted to store other information about the author then that would be a good reason to create the author table.

Comment: In your second test case you don't have an index on [song.title], which makes the comparison a bit unfair.

Answer (score 0):

From my pov :

- if you have a database that is for lookup purposes only, where a single row will provide you all the answers you need for your queries -> go without normalization
- is your database going to be updated? Go with normalization to provide consistancy and less clutter.